# AERO can i have it?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, aero, display-driver, nvidia-graphics-card

Can i have aero on this graphic card . does it support aero on windows 7
ASUS V9570/TD (nVIDIA Geforce FX5700) 256 MB
Please if someone knows are nVIDIA GEforce FX5700 or ASUS V9570/TD Supports aero
this 2 cards are same but another names.

Comment: I very much doubt it. I was reading from another SU question which stated that the whole FX series was utter rubbish when it came to Direct X. He then finished with it was supported on vista. Vista used aero so...

Comment: The Geforce FX series supports DirectX 9, which is the requirement for Aero Glass. try if you can get a WDDM 1.0 driver in Win7

Answer (score 1):

As stated by magicandre1981, Aero uses DirectX 9.

If your card handles DirectX 9 and if you have compatible drivers for it, you should be able to activate Aero.